# How come the position of "arr[i] = []" make the code crash?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried making some multidimensional arrays in Javascript:

```
var arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    arr[i] = [];
    arr[i][j] = i*j
  }
}
```

But when checking the result with:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    console.log(arr[i][j])
  }
}
```

I came across a bunch of "undefined"...
But, simply by switching `arr[i] = []` from where it is to between the "for" statements:

```
var arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      arr[i] = [];
      for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        arr[i][j] = i*j
      }
    }
```

It worked fine. WHY????

Comment: Step through the code for `i = 0` and `j = 0..1`.

Comment: B/c you reassign an empty array to a[i] for every j, so the only index actually having sth is j=4.

Answer (score 5):

Because the first way you are initializing arr[i] = [] every time, so only the last j element is set.

arr[i][4] is the only one that gets set, arr[i][0] through arr[i][3] are no longer defined. Did I explain that well enough? Let me try adding a comment on the line you are having problems with:

```
var arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    arr[i] = []; // 2nd time through the loop arr[i][0] is gone because you just re-initialized the array
    arr[i][j] = i*j
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is well explained!

Answer (score 0):

Each time you repeat the inner for loop, the array contained in `arr[i]` gets overwritten as a new, empty array.  Moving that before the start of the inner for loop keeps `arr[i]` from being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You keep overwriting your array in the inner loop!